# Octave (IO package error) cannot run C++ compiled programs

Tags: c++, homebrew, octave

I am in an instrumental analysis class. We are using Octave to write our lab notebooks. One of our functions we need to use is `pkg install -forge statistics`. When I enter that I get

> ```
> error: the following dependencies were unsatisfied: statistics needs io >= 1.0.18
> ```

When I try to `pkg update -forge io`, I get

> ```
> warning: pkg: package io is not installed - skipping update warning: called from
>     pkg at line 572 column 13
> ```

When I try `pkg install -forge io`, it tries to install it, then I get

> ```
> configure: error: in `/var/folders/7z/xkztb9z11xs99kzrkzrd4rpr0000gn/T/oct-okgmrt/io-2.6.1/src':
> configure: error: cannot run C++ compiled programs.
> If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
> See `config.log' for more details
> checking for mkoctfile... /usr/local/Cellar/octave/5.2.0_7/bin/mkoctfile-5.2.0
> checking for octave-config... /usr/local/Cellar/octave/5.2.0_7/bin/octave-config-5.2.0
> checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
> checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
> checking for suffix of executables... 
> checking whether we are cross compiling... 
> pkg: error running the configure script for io.
> error: called from
>     configure_make at line 82 column 9
>     install at line 190 column 7
>     pkg at line 441 column 9
> ```

I have tried reinstalling Homebrew and Octave, I still get all the same errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have Xcode installed? Homebrew installs programs compiled with Xcode, so likely the Octave you have is compiled with that too. When you try to install a package that needs a compilation step, it needs to find a compiler that is compatible with the one that was used to compile Octave. If you don't have Xcode, but maybe GCC installed though Homebrew, then it'll be using the wrong compiler and things won't work together.

Comment: I have X-code select installed.

Comment: if you type `g++ --version` in a terminal window, does it say "Apple clang" or does it say "GCC"?

Comment: Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)

Comment: The error message says "See 'config.log' for more details". Have you looked at that file? What does it say?

Comment: I'm going to be honest, I have no idea how to open that.

Comment: If you know where the file is, you can type in your terminal window `less /path/to/config.log` (replacing the "/path/to" with whatever location the file is at).